# How to present AWS KMS public keys in JWKs format

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-kms, jwk

After creating a key pair in AWS KMS service I can see the public key looks something like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
J1UJQVArKIBiUNUgvkEamuz4treK5qSCJeUD+TcN9lPEQTXrApYV+CcXnuQJql472gPGtTNbyE
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But when clients invoke the jwks endpoint url (e.g. https://my-authorization-service.com/.well-known/jwks)

I want the response to look like any other conventional (e.g. google jwks etc.) jwks response, like this:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kty": "RSA",
  "use": "sig",
  "n": "vYjDQCjiQCjiQCjiQCjiQCji",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "kid": "79adDfP_ggD-fuxsFWdkd",
  "x5t": "aaaaaaabbbbbbbbcccccccc",
  "x5c": [
    "the_x5c_bla_bla"
  ]
}
```

The purpose of this JWKs endpoint is to have authorizers refer to this endpoint to fetch the correct JWKs key in order to verify/validate a JWT token that has been signed by the private key.

**How can I present the KMS public key in a JWKs format as described above ? or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is a matter of exporting the RSA public key to jwk format.

This was answered on another stackoverflow post, [link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72323842/3263659)

In Javascript (NodeJS runtime) you can do it natively (From Node 15.9.0 or above):

```
import { createPublicKey } from 'crypto'
const pemPublicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
const publicKey = createPublicKey(pemPublicKey)
console.log(publicKey.export({ format: 'jwk' }))
```

So I had to extrat the KMS public key and export/convert the key as shown above. then finally present the key as required, and have it available via my jwks endpoint.